# Why these memory values never change in GDB?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, stack-trace

Once again, thank you for the great help so far.

The source code:

```
int main()
{ 
   int a = 20;
   int b = 10;
   int c;
   c = a + b;
return 0;   
}

Reading symbols from /home/jwxie/a.out...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x80483fa: file demoo.cpp, line 3.
Starting program: /home/jwxie/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at demoo.cpp:3
3      int a = 20;
(gdb) x/wx $ebp-8
0xbffff3a0: 0x08048420
(gdb) x/wx $ebp-4
0xbffff3a4: 0x00000000
(gdb) info locals
a = 0
b = 134513696
c = 3903476
(gdb) x/wx $ebp-8
0xbffff3a0: 0x08048420
(gdb) x/wx $ebp-12
0xbffff39c: 0x003b8ff4

-- Now execute int a = 20;
(gdb) stepi
4      int b = 10;

(gdb) x/wx $ebp-4
0xbffff3a4: 0x00000014

(gdb) info locals
a = 20
b = 134513696
c = 3903476
```

(1) 
I noticed that the values of a, b and c prior to any of the assignment remain the same no matter how many times I restart the debug or reboot.

I even disabled optimization:   **g++ -g -O0 demo.cpp**

Why is that?

(2)
Another strange thing is that, after each stepi, esp never changed, unlike in Visual Studio, we can observe the change of esp and ebp...
The log is can be found in here:  [info registers](http://codepad.org/9uMDkBTa)

What is the problem here? 
Thank you very much.

---

EDIT
 Yes. Thank you. Here is the disas

```
    (gdb) disas /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
2   { 
   0x080483f4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483f5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483f7 <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp

3      int a = 20;
   0x080483fa <+6>: movl   $0x14,-0x4(%ebp)

4      int b = 10;
   0x08048401 <+13>:    movl   $0xa,-0x8(%ebp)

5      int c;
6      c = a + b;
   0x08048408 <+20>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804840b <+23>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804840e <+26>:    lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%eax
   0x08048411 <+29>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)

7   return 0;   
   0x08048414 <+32>:    mov    $0x0,%eax

8   }
   0x08048419 <+37>:    leave  
   0x0804841a <+38>:    ret    

End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Could you show us the disassembly of main()? I'm suspecting, there isn't much (if any) code to deal with a, b and c in there.

Comment: have you tried `step` instead of `stepi`?  `stepi` steps a single assember command. `step` steps 1 line of c++

Comment: @Alan Yes. ESP will not change. In VS, ESP is changing as we step through each instruction (be it step, or stepi).

Comment: @JohnWong: I think I misunderstood your question. a, b and c may have any values before they get initialized. The fact that they have the same uninitialized values every time only means that the execution environment doesn't change much, that the memory behind a, b and c is used in exactly the same way every time. It doesn't have to be that way, but it may.

Comment: @Alex Thank you. In VS, I believe the value we get from memory windows is the actual garbage value in memory. Is there an equivalent way of observing that in GDB?  THanks.

Comment: @JohnWong: That I don't know. And it's something that can depend on both the debugger and OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that variable values, before initialization, will always be the same.  Some debuggers will initialize memory to fixed values, e.g. 0xDEADBEEF, some will clear to zero, others will not do anything and you get what was in memory.

Comment: Okay. Yes. It seems like the first variable is always zero, after testing this on 3 different pcs. Thanks.

Comment: My bad. I usually check off the answer after I complete my assignment or totally understand the answer. Thank you.